# Overlaying subplot ggraph

Tags: r, ggplot2, overlay, subplot, ggraph

I need to **overlay** a set of **subplots** over a ggraph. Every plot correspond to an especific node so they must be placed **using the coordinates of every node**. The following code creates the graph and the set of subplots to overlay.

```
 # Create the graph
 library(data.table)
 library(igraph)
 library(ggraph)

 mydata <- data.table(from=c("John", "John", "Jim"), to=c("John", "Jim", "Jack"))
 graph <- graph_from_data_frame(mydata)
 V(graph)$class <- c("John", "Jim", "Jack")

 ggraph(graph, layout = 'linear') + 
 geom_edge_link() + 
 geom_node_point() +
 geom_node_text(aes(label = class))

 # Plots to overlay
 John <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) + geom_histogram(fill = "red") + 
 ggtitle("John")
 Jim <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(depth)) + geom_histogram(fill = "blue") + 
 ggtitle("Jim")
 Jack <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(price)) + geom_histogram(fill = "green") + 
 ggtitle("Jack")
```

The following image ilustrates the actual and desired result. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ggraph::create_layout` to extract x and y coordinates of the nodes, and then use `purrr::pmap` to apply `ggplot2::annotation_custom` to each of your subplots.

```
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)

# Your code, mostly unchanged (removed data.table)
mydata <- data.frame(from=c("John", "John", "Jim"), to=c("John", "Jim", "Jack"))
graph <- graph_from_data_frame(mydata)
V(graph)$class <- c("John", "Jim", "Jack")


John <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) + geom_histogram(fill = "red") + 
  ggtitle("John")
Jim <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(depth)) + geom_histogram(fill = "blue") + 
  ggtitle("Jim")
Jack <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(price)) + geom_histogram(fill = "green") + 
  ggtitle("Jack")

# New code
graph_df <- create_layout(graph, layout = 'linear')
```

---

`graph_df` is a dataframe with contents:

> ```
>   x y name class ggraph.orig_index circular ggraph.index
> 1 1 0 John  John                 1    FALSE            1
> 2 2 0  Jim   Jim                 2    FALSE            2
> 3 3 0 Jack  Jack                 3    FALSE            3
> ```

You can call `ggraph(graph_df)` directly; under the hood `ggraph(graph)` was doing the same steps.

---

Now we make a nested list, where the first element is a list of the ggplot objects we want to use for insets (making sure they're in the right order, relative to their order in `graph_df`). The second element is a list of the x coordinates, and the third element is a list of the y coordinates. Then we apply a function that constructs grobs to inset, using the x and y coordinates to define a box where it will go in the final plot.

```
grobs <- pmap(.l = list(plots = list(John, Jim, Jack), 
                        x = as.list(graph_df$x), 
                        y = as.list(graph_df$y)),

              .f = function(plots, x, y) {

    annotation_custom(grob = ggplotGrob(plots + theme_grey(base_size = 4)),
                      xmin = x - .25, xmax = x + .25,
                      ymin = y + .1,  ymax = y + .6)
  })
```

Then your code from above just needs to have this object added on and some fiddling with the limits:

```
ggraph(graph_df) + 
  geom_edge_link() + 
  geom_node_point() +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = class)) + 
  expand_limits(x = c(0.5,3.5)) +
  coord_equal() +
  grobs
```

[image]

Some notes:

- The construction of the inset plots can also likely be done programmatically using `purrr` functions.
- The `base_size =` argument in the function we created will need to be fiddled with to your liking.
- The offsets for x and y in the function also have to be done manually, based on the range of coordinates in your actual plot.